# Evaluate org-babel header arguments consistently

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ess, r

Consider the following `org-babel` code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R* :dir ~/_test
getwd()
#+END_SRC
```

When I `C-c C-c` on my source block, I get the following result, as expected:

```
#+RESULTS:
: /Users/.../_test
```

But now if I now open the block with `org-edit-special` and place point on `getwd()` and run `ess-eval-line` (or `ess-eval-region`) my header arguments are completely ignored and *R* spits out my default working directory:

```
/Users/.../org
```

What's more, header args like `:dir` are only evaluated the first time that the block is executed. So if I want to work through my code line-by-line in `org-edit-special` and then I return to org-mode and run `org-babel-execute-src-block` the `:dir` argument will not get passed into the `*R*` interpreter.

I would like to make this behavior consistent so that:

1. Header args are evaluated and passed into the environment every time the code is executed.
2. Arguments like `:dir` or `:var` etc. are captured and passed into the interpreter, whether the code is first run as a block or accessed line-by-line through `org-edit-special`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `ess-eval-*` doesn't have anything to do with Org mode, so why would you expect it to honor the execution environment that Org mode sets up *around* it? But to go even further, forget about R:  `org-edit-special` just sets up an editing environment for the code; it does not set up an execution environment, so *it* does not know anything about the header args. If you want the header args to be consulted, you will need to use evaluation mechanisms that consult them (i.e. `org-babel`).

Comment: Okay, so if we've ruled out faulty settings/config, it sounds like I need to override (or advise) `ess-eval-region`... any thoughts?

Comment: I think that's the wrong thing to do: just finish up the edit, go back to the Org mode source block and execute it: it knows how to set up the execution environment already. Getting `ess-eval-*` (or more importantly `org-edit-special` since `ess-eval-* is specific to R src block only) to parse the Org mode buffer, understand header args and set up the proper execution environment is IMO way too complicated and does not buy you much (if anything).